# how to filter json data in clojure

Tags: json, clojure

I have a JSON data of like this. I need to filter only `name` and `uuid` from this data. I have used JSON filters `data["main_cat"]["data"]["name"]` but I didn't get value to the key name here is the json data.

```
[
    {
        "main_cat": {
            "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/properties",
            "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/relationships",
            "labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/labels",
            "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/relationships/in",
            "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/relationships/out",
            "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/properties/{key}",
            "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
            "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
            "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/traverse/{returnType}",
            "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/relationships/all",
            "extensions": {},
            "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
            "metadata": {
                "id": 203,
                "labels": [
                    "Category"
                ]
            },
            "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
            "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203",
            "data": {
                "timestamp": 1439216657489,
                "name": "grocery & staples",
                "uuid": "7be98425-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd",
                "main": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "main_cat": {
            "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/properties",
            "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/relationships",
            "labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/labels",
            "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/relationships/in",
            "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/relationships/out",
            "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/properties/{key}",
            "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
            "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
            "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/traverse/{returnType}",
            "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/relationships/all",
            "extensions": {},
            "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
            "metadata": {
                "id": 207,
                "labels": [
                    "Category"
                ]
            },
            "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
            "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/207",
            "data": {
                "timestamp": 1439216657489,
                "name": "health care",
                "uuid": "7be98421-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd",
                "main": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "main_cat": {
            "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/properties",
            "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/relationships",
            "labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/labels",
            "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/relationships/in",
            "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/relationships/out",
            "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/properties/{key}",
            "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
            "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
            "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/traverse/{returnType}",
            "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/relationships/all",
            "extensions": {},
            "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
            "metadata": {
                "id": 208,
                "labels": [
                    "Category"
                ]
            },
            "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
            "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/208",
            "data": {
                "timestamp": 1439216657489,
                "name": "household",
                "uuid": "7be9d243-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd",
                "main": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "main_cat": {
            "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/properties",
            "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/relationships",
            "labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/labels",
            "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/relationships/in",
            "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/relationships/out",
            "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/properties/{key}",
            "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
            "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
            "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/traverse/{returnType}",
            "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/relationships/all",
            "extensions": {},
            "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
            "metadata": {
                "id": 190,
                "labels": [
                    "Category"
                ]
            },
            "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
            "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/190",
            "data": {
                "timestamp": 1439216657489,
                "name": "food mart",
                "uuid": "7be90ef4-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd",
                "main": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "main_cat": {
            "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/properties",
            "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/relationships",
            "labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/labels",
            "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/relationships/in",
            "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/relationships/out",
            "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/properties/{key}",
            "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
            "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
            "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/traverse/{returnType}",
            "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/relationships/all",
            "extensions": {},
            "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
            "metadata": {
                "id": 171,
                "labels": [
                    "Category"
                ]
            },
            "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
            "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/171",
            "data": {
                "timestamp": 1439216657489,
                "name": "beauty care & personal care",
                "uuid": "7be872b3-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd",
                "main": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "main_cat": {
            "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/properties",
            "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/relationships",
            "labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/labels",
            "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/relationships/in",
            "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/relationships/out",
            "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/properties/{key}",
            "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
            "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
            "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/traverse/{returnType}",
            "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/relationships/all",
            "extensions": {},
            "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
            "metadata": {
                "id": 179,
                "labels": [
                    "Category"
                ]
            },
            "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
            "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/179",
            "data": {
                "timestamp": 1439216657489,
                "name": "fruits and vegetables",
                "uuid": "7be93603-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd",
                "main": true
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would select `name` and `uuid` from a sequence of maps.

```
(let [data [{"main_cat" ;; keys elided for brevity
             {"self" "http//localhost7474/db/data/node/207",
              "data" {"timestamp" 1439216657489,
                      "name"      "health care",
                      "uuid"      "7be98421-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd",
                      "main"      true}}}]]
  (map (fn [m] (-> m (get-in ["main_cat" "data"]) (select-keys ["name" "uuid"]))) data))
;=> ({"name" "health care", "uuid" "7be98421-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd"})
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the JSON object parsed into `json_map`, another way to solve this would be:

```
(map #(select-keys (get-in % [:main_cat :data]) [:uuid :name]) json_map)
```

This is first going into your map via [get-in](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in) and just grabbing at that one sub-hash you need. Then it's using [select-keys](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys) to grab the keys it needs.

This won't be as straightforward when you need data outside of that map. In which case I suggest using something like [Balagan](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/balagan) for hash querying.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I am also not an expert in Clojure, but here is how I would solve it (using data.json), wrapped in a function:

```
(defn filter-json [json-string]
 (let [data (json/read-str json-string :key-fn keyword)]
  (map #(dissoc (:data (:main_cat %)) :timestamp :main) data)))
```

The result of your posted data would be:

> ({:name "grocery & staples", :uuid "7be98425-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd"} {:name "health care", :uuid "7be98421-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd"} {:name "household", :uuid "7be9d243-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd"} {:name "food mart", :uuid "7be90ef4-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd"} {:name "beauty care & personal care", :uuid "7be872b3-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd"} {:name "fruits and vegetables", :uuid "7be93603-3f6b-11e5-83a2-ec0ec46eeadd"})

You first read the JSON String with `read-str` (if you not already did) and specify, that you would like to access the structure with keywords. Then you can use the keywords to narrow it down until you get to the "data" section, where you dissoc the unwanted properties.

I think this solution can be optimized, I am looking forward to every solution for an improvement!